# T4 indentation in generated C# code

Tags: c#, t4

When using T4 to generate C# code, I can't get correct identation with TABS scattered around:

```
public partial class Foo : Base
{
        public int C { get; set; }
        [MappedProperty("A.B[{C}].Foo")]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using a seemingly correctly indented .TT code similar to the following:

```
public partial class <#= ViewModelName #>
{
    <#  foreach(var property in ViewModelProperties) { #> 
        <# if(property.Mapping != null) { #>
        [MappedProperty("<#= property.Mapping #>")]
        <# } #>
        public <#= property.TypeDeclaration #> <#= property.MemberName #> { get; set; }
    <# } #>
}
```

This code snippet reflects what I've already tried to do: make control statements and blocks to a single line as much as possible.

Comment: try move `public ...` on same line as `if` end: `<# } #>public ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like to do it this way and never had any problems.

```
public partial class <#= ViewModelName #>
{
<#
    foreach(var property in ViewModelProperties) { 
        if(property.Mapping != null) { 
#>
    [MappedProperty("<#= property.Mapping #>")]
<#
        }
#>
    public <#= property.TypeDeclaration #> <#= property.MemberName #> { get; set; }
<#
    }
#>
}
```

Comment: yeap, clean way to go, I do the same and avoid most of the issues

Answer (score 6):

Use [`PushIndent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.texttransformation.pushindent.aspx), [`PopIndent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.texttransformation.popindent.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) and [`ClearIndent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.texttransformation.clearindent.aspx) like so:

```
public partial class <#= ViewModelName #>
{
<# PushIndent("   "); #>
<#  foreach(var property in ViewModelProperties) { #> 
<# if(property.Mapping != null) { #>
[MappedProperty("<#= property.Mapping #>")]
<# } #>
public <#= property.TypeDeclaration #> <#= property.MemberName #> { get; set; }
<# } #>
<# PopIndent(); #>
}
```

or alternatively...

```
public partial class <#= ViewModelName #>
{
<# 
   PushIndent("   "); 
   foreach(var property in ViewModelProperties) {
      if(property.Mapping != null) { 
         WriteLine("[MappedProperty({0})]", property.Mapping);
      }
      WriteLine("public {0} {1} {{ get; set; }}", property.TypeDeclaration, property.MemberName);
   }
   PopIndent(); 
#>
}
```

Comment: I think its not how most people expect to define their templates, not very readable, but still, nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be a bit less messy with your whitespaces and '<#' and the result will be more expectable:

1. you dont need to use '<#' in half of the places, `foreach` and `if` may stay within one. That way you'll reduce the potential whitespaces outside tags and make it more readable.
2. your `public` line starts with double tab, so it generates a property with indented with double tab instead of a single one. Remove one.
3. all the whitespaces outside '<#' tags will be printed, remove them, leave only what's necessary outside the tags (before and after them). Otherwise they will accumulate and break your formatting.